# Failed to create session. Request timed out in appium inspector only for Android devices

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-inspector

i'm using appium 2.1.3 and i try on macOS,for ios devices it will work fine to me,but when want to get android inspector it will show this message "Failed to create session. Request timed out" and its my desire capabilities

```
{
  "appium:platformName": "android",
  "appium:deviceName": "emulator-5554",
  "appium:appPackage": "com.saucelabs.mydemoapp.rn",
  "appium:appActivity": ".MainActivity",
  "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2"
}
```

and when i run my script it return this message:

```
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No application is open
open app                                                              | FAIL |
ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Comment: Could you post appium server logs

Comment: [debug] [ADB] Starting apksigner: /usr/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Xss1m -jar /Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/34.0.0/lib/apksigner.jar verify --print-certs /Users/macbookpro/.appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-v5.12.3.apk
[HTTP] <-- POST /session - - ms - -